# how to imitate Pandas' index-based querying in Polars?

Tags: python, data-science, python-polars, querying

Any idea what I can do to imitate the below pandas code using polars? Polars doesn't have indexes like pandas so I couldn't figure out what I can do .

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ([21,123], [132,412], [23, 43]), columns = ['c1', 'c2']).set_index("c1")
print(df.loc[[23, 132]])
```

and it prints

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 43 |
| 132 | 412 |

the only polars conversion I could figure out to do is

```
df = pl.DataFrame(data = ([21,123], [132,412], [23, 43]), schema = ['c1', 'c2'])
print(df.filter(pl.col("c1").is_in([23, 132])))
```

but it prints

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| 132 | 412 |
| 23 | 43 |

which is okay but the rows are not in the order I gave. I gave [23, 132] and want the output rows to be in the same order, like how pandas' output has.

I can use a sort() later yes, but the original data I use this on has like 30Million rows so I'm looking for something that's as fast as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using a `left join` to accomplish this.  This will maintain the order corresponding to your list of index values.  (And it is quite performant.)

For example, let's start with this shuffled DataFrame.

```py
nbr_rows = 30_000_000

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'c1': pl.arange(0, nbr_rows, eager=True).shuffle(2),
    'c2': pl.arange(0, nbr_rows, eager=True).shuffle(3),
})
df
```

```
shape: (30000000, 2)
┌──────────┬──────────┐
│ c1       ┆ c2       │
│ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ 4052015  ┆ 20642741 │
│ 7787054  ┆ 17007051 │
│ 20246150 ┆ 19445431 │
│ 1309992  ┆ 6495751  │
│ ...      ┆ ...      │
│ 10371090 ┆ 4791782  │
│ 26281644 ┆ 12350777 │
│ 6740626  ┆ 24888572 │
│ 22573405 ┆ 14885989 │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

And these index values:

```py
nbr_index_values = 10_000
s1 = pl.Series(name='c1', values=pl.arange(0, nbr_index_values, eager=True).shuffle())
s1
```

```
shape: (10000,)
Series: 'c1' [i64]
[
        1754
        6716
        3485
        7058
        7216
        1040
        1832
        3921
        1639
        6734
        5560
        7596
        ...
        4243
        4455
        894
        7806
        9291
        1883
        9947
        3309
        2030
        7731
        4706
        8528
        8426
]
```

We now perform a `left join` to obtain the rows corresponding to the index values.  (Note that the list of index values is the left DataFrame in this join.)

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
df2 = (
    s1.to_frame()
    .join(
        df,
        on='c1',
        how='left'
    )
)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)

df2
```

```
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
0.8427023889998964
```

```
shape: (10000, 2)
┌──────┬──────────┐
│ c1   ┆ c2       │
│ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ i64  ┆ i64      │
╞══════╪══════════╡
│ 1754 ┆ 15734441 │
│ 6716 ┆ 20631535 │
│ 3485 ┆ 20199121 │
│ 7058 ┆ 15881128 │
│ ...  ┆ ...      │
│ 7731 ┆ 19420197 │
│ 4706 ┆ 16918008 │
│ 8528 ┆ 5278904  │
│ 8426 ┆ 18927935 │
└──────┴──────────┘
```

Notice how the rows are in the same order as the index values.  We can verify this:

```py
s1.series_equal(df2.get_column('c1'), strict=True)
```

```
>>> s1.series_equal(df2.get_column('c1'), strict=True)
True
```

And the performance is quite good.  On my 32-core system, this takes less than a second.